# Setting parameter in ORDER BY of named query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, named-query

I am using a named query as below;

```
@NamedQuery(name = "MyClass.findAll", query = "SELECT .... ORDER BY user.:sortColumn :sortOrder")
```

I want the sortColumn and sortOrder to be set dynamically.

So I use;

```
query.setParameter("sortColumn", sortColumn);
query.setParameter("sortOrder", sortOrder);
```

I can pass/set the parameter in the WHERE clause without any issues.

However I am getting unexpected token error for :sortColumn

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you agree to work with a JPQL query (but not a `NamedQuery` which are checked on deployment), you can define a parameter in the Query String, and before passing the Query String to the `EntityManager`, simply replace the parameters, with what you want. Of course you need some sanity check of the parameter values.

e.g

```
String queryStr = "SELECT .... ORDER BY user.:sortColumn :sortOrder";
//TODO sanity check of passedSortCol, passedSortOrder
queryStr = queryStr.replace(":sortColumn", passedSortCol);
queryStr = queryStr.replace(":sortOrder", passedSortOrder);
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The query analyzer expects **identifier** -not variable- instead of

```
user.:sortColumn
```

also it expects **[key/reserved]word** -not variable- instead of

```
:sortOrder
```

so, you better use different queries for order field and order type.

Answer (score 0):

For a named query, **ORDER BY** clause couldn't be parameterised at run-time unlike **WHERE** and **HAVING** clause. The solution for such problem is to go for Criteria API.

Comment: Thx...can u provide ref example for Criteria API